# Android Eddystone - URL Chrome Physical Web

Tags: beacon, google-beacon-platform, eddystone-url

I have a beacon that is transmitting Eddystone - URL. I can locate my beacon using the Physical Web app in Android. I [read](https://9to5google.com/2016/02/10/chrome-49-eddystone-beacon-recognition/) that from Chrome 49 Physical web is by default supported by chrome but I'm using Chrome 69 version but I didn't get any nearby notification. In short my questions are,

1. Does Chrome by default support physical web? and if it does should I have to open the chrome app to get my notifications displayed?
2. Do people need to have any specific app to get nearby notifications?

Answer (score 1):

You must actively turn on Physical Web in Chrome for Android's privacy settings as described [here](https://google.github.io/physical-web/try-physical-web).

These notifications can also be delivered by Nearby, which requires Google Play Services, but no other apps on the phone.  Most Android devices outside of China have Google Play Services installed, but those in China as well as Amazon Fire tablets and some other devices do not, and will not receive these notifications.  The link above also describes how users must opt-in to Nearby notifications.  If they do not opt-in, they will not get the notifications.

Comment: Got clarified about the scenario but as per the link you shared I couldn't find the Physical Web setting in Chrome->Privacy. I have Android Marshmallow and chrome 69.